# Android: On Click gradual visibility change

Tags: java, android, button, visibility, tablerow

I have got a little problem which is for me impossible to solve. I've got lots of TableRows called Radek_X and they are set to be `android:visibility="gone".`
And I need that if you for the first time, click on button(there is only one button for that process) it will change Radek_1 to `android:visibility="visible"` if you click on the button for the second time it will change Radek_2 from gone to visible, while Radek_1 is still visible. And so on for all others TableRows. I'm really desperate. I will be very grateful for any help! Have a nice day!

Here is my java file

```
package jansoldat.formular100;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableRow;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button buttonPridejStaniceni;
    TableRow Radek_2, Radek_3, Radek_4,Radek_5,Radek_6;

    @Override
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonPridejStaniceni = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPridejStaniceni);
        Radek_2 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.Radek_2);
        Radek_3 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.Radek_3);
        Radek_4 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.Radek_4);
        Radek_5 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.Radek_5);
        Radek_6 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.Radek_6);

    }

    public void PridejDalsiStaniceniClicked(View v)
    {
        Radek_2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Radek_3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Radek_3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Radek_4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Radek_5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Radek_6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}


`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually easier than you think, change your onClick method, which I assume you're setting by xml to `PridejDalsiStaniceniClicked` to this:

```
int[] views = new int[]{R.id.Radek_2,R.id.Radek_3,R.id.Radek_4};//...
int counter = 0;
public void PridejDalsiStaniceniClicked(View v)
{
    findViewById(views[counter]).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if(counter<views.length){
        counter++;
    }
}
```

What happens inside is that we will fetch the view that matches the counter of times pressed while there are still views in the array. **Some people don't realize that view ids are integers** and can be stored in an array like in the example.

Comment: It's working, thank you so much sir!! But Can I have a second question? How to fix that app fall after it depleted all tablerows? I know it's apparently a silly question but I'm new in Android programming.

Comment: I shouldn't fail if the ids of the views are correct, to prevent exceptions we have the if statement